# how can I compare the two lists with/without iterating over each list

Tags: java, java-8

How can I compare the above two lists with/without iterating over each list?I would like to compare the people1 list without iterating against people list. when matching occurs it has print the matched object else it has to print non matching object. I have to do this without iterating second list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    String name;
    int age;
    String mail;

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public Person(String name, int age, String mail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return getMail().compareTo(p.getMail());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        people.add(new Person("Homer", 38, "shankar@gmail.com"));
        people.add(new Person("Marge", 35, "shankar6@gmail.com"));
        people.add(new Person("Bart", 15, "ramr@gmail.com"));
        people.add(new Person("Lisa", 13, "ramkumar@gmail.com"));

        System.out.println("\t" + people);

        List<Person> people1 = new ArrayList<Person>();

        people1.add(new Person("jug", 38, "jug@gmail.com"));
        people1.add(new Person("benny", 35, "benny@gmail.com"));
        people1.add(new Person("Bart", 15, "ramr@gmail.com"));
        people1.add(new Person("Lisa", 13, "ramkumar@gmail.com"));

        for (Person people : people) {
            if (people1.contains( people)) { 
                System.out.println("matched");
                System.out.println(people);
            } else {
                System.out.println("not matched");
                System.out.println(people);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
matched
Bart : 15 :ramr@gmail.com
```

Comment: what is this `people==people1` you are comparing a people object with a people list and you are comparing using `==`. This is totally wrong.

Comment: people.retainAll(people1) is this what you are searching for?

Comment: yes contains of yes.

Comment: `new Person("Lisa", 13, "ramkumar@gmail.com")` also matche no?

Comment: Can't be done without iterating __both__ lists at least once each.  You, personally, might not have to write the code that actually does the iterating, but iteration will be happening nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need have a correct implementation of `equals` method. Then you can use `List#retainAll` which "Retains only the elements in this list that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection".

Copy the original list to some list if you want to keep the original list like: `copyofPeople`  then you can use `copyofPeople.retainAll(people1)`. Now if `copyofPeople`  is blank (`copyofPeople.size()==0`) then there is no element in common.

If your logical equality depends on the person's email the then equals method should looks like below:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (mail == null) {
            if (other.mail != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!mail.equals(other.mail))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks amit for the reply, let me apply this and check once

Answer (score 1):

[Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) have:

```
people.retainAll(people1) // for intersection
people.addAll(people1) // for union
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Java 8 then you can also use stream for this.

```
    for (Person p : people) {
            if(people1.stream().filter(i -> i.equals(p)).findFirst().isPresent()){
                System.out.println("matched");
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not matched");
                System.out.println(p);
            }
     }
```

Here i am overriding equals method in Person class to return true if all the properties of one object matches other.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if(getName() == p.getName() && getAge() == p.getAge() && getMail() == p.getMail())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```